# Ubuntu bash echo "$PASSWORD" | sudo -S WID=$(cat /var/lib/FILE)

Tags: sudo, cat

/var/lib/FILE root:root 0600 (One line of text)

How can I read the /var/lib/FILE into $WID

```
 echo "$PASSWORD" | sudo -S WID=$(cat /var/lib/FILE) not working for me.
```

Comment: You may want to check the [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and especially the first part about code blocks and inline code formatting

Answer (score 1):

If you need the file's contents in a variable in your current shell, above won't work as the assignment is done in a subshell and be lost after quitting the subshell (admittedly there are shells that do not lose the variable).

For `sudo` to work, you need to have an entry in `sudoers` allowing you to run a command. A variable assignment is not a command, thus above will fail again.

If you want a file's contents in a variable without having the permission to read that file, try

```
WID=$(echo "a" | sudo -S cat /var/lib/FILE)
```